# Solution if Microsoft Azure Push Notification using Notification Hub fails for some numbers

Tags: azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

Currently I am working on demo implementation of *push notification* using *Microsoft Azure Notification Hub*.

We have to send notification to 500k numbers. I was thinking about the condition where what will happen in case the notification is sent to 300k numbers and fails for 200k.

Do we have any solution at Azure end to deal with this situation?

Is there any way at azure where we can send notification again to only those numbers for whom the notification failed?

Comment: You able to get any information around it? Do you know if there is a way to identify if the message if been failed to some specific devices?

Comment: We had a conversation with their team and sadly they said they do not provide any such facility at this moment and may come up with something in near future

Comment: Thanks Radhika.. i got the same response as well :)